# Eclipse Formatter - Ignore content in if conditions

Tags: java, eclipse, coding-style, formatter

I have been setting up the eclipse formatter and quite close to our desired outcome except for the following. I'm trying to ignore line wrapping for the conditions within the if statement

For example

My desired outcome is

```
if (callback.getType().equals("NameCallback")) {
                            callback.getInput()
                                    .get(0)
                                    .setValue(testUser.getUsername());
                        }
```

but instead I'm getting

```
if (callback.getType()
            .equals("NameCallback")) {
        callback.getInput()
                .get(0)
                .setValue(testUser.getUsername());
                    }
```

In the formatter I have set Line wrapping -> Function Calls -> Qualified Innovations to a line wrapping policy of 'Wrap all elements, except first element if not necessary' and force split. This works fine but our preference is to not have this rule invoked for if statement conditions or inside of () if easier. I know I can setup the On/Off tags for the formatter but hoping there is a way to get the same result without having to do this. Any ideas would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to customize the way you format an `if` `else` blocks, you need to jump to **Control Statements** :

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did have a look at this and tried a few options but it doesn't seem to have an option to stop the line wrapping for the method calls